# Does Twitter support OAuth 2.0?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0

I want to integrate Twitter with my Android application. Can I do this using OAuth 2.0?

I have searched the internet but couldn't find any good explanation regarding this. If anyone has done this before, can you please guide me through this. I saw in a old post [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/397) that Twitter doesn't support OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, no, Twitter [still uses OAuth 1.0a](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) for most parts of their backend. Since march however, they support the OAuth 2 [client credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) for *[application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/application-only-authentication)*.

This means, if you:

- have an application that only shows tweets from other users or stuff like that, you can get authorized using OAuth 2.
- want any users to use your app to post tweets or do anything else on a user's behalf, you have to struggle with OAuth 1.0a.

You should check out the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library, which abstracts most of the OAuth 1 hassle away from you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan.In my application I want to retrieve the oauth token and oauth secret  from twitter and pass it to a REST protocol to achieve my work.Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.

Comment: I am glad to know that its possible.Could you pleas guide me with some relevant link how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest:

> "... we're releasing our application-only authentication scheme, based
>   on the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow."

Posted to dev.twitter 2013-03-11 https://dev.twitter.com/blog/application-only-authentication (current: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2013/application-only-authentication.html)